# Unity Dependency Injection and Helper functions

Tags: c#, dependency-injection

I have a set of services that are used to read/write to the database. These get injected into my controllers:

```
ISystemSettingService _systemSettingService = null;
IStatusTypeService _statusTypeservice = null;

public MyController(
    ISystemSettingService systemSettingService,
    IStatusTypeService statusTypeservice)
{
    _systemSettingService = systemSettingService;
    _statusTypeservice = statusTypeservice;
}
```

So when I need something from `_systemSettingService` I can easily get it. Now I also have some static helper classes/functions which I call from `MyController`. In these functions I often need access to the services so I can access the DB. e.g. I have a `Validate(string userData, ISystemSettingService systemSettingService)` function that accepts some data passed in from the user.

So far, into the `Validate` function I have been passing in the `_systemSettingService` so I can use it. I'm not sure this is correct.

My question - is my approach correct or, in the `Validate` function should I be creating a unity container to `Resolve` an instance of my `ISystemSettingService` or, as I have been reading about, should my helper class NOT be static, and I should inject `ISystemSettingService` into the constructor which will apparently make unit testing easier.

I'm a bit confused! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your questions sounds a little bit confused about `Validate` being a function or a class, but for sake of simplicity, let us assume it is a function.

If I got you right, you want to make sure your `Validate` function uses internally the same `ISystemSettingService` object as `MyController`. Passing it as a parameter like

```
 Validate(userData, _systemSettingService)
```

at all places where is `Validate`is called is surely a working approach. However, by making `Validate` non-static, you can actually reach the same goal in a more readable and less error-prone fashion. So if all calls to the static version of `Validate` would use `_systemSettingService` as a second parameter, with no exceptions, then making it non-static and saving the second parameter is IMHO the better alternative.

Usage of a DI container for the helper function will probably make the code longer, less readable, more complex and error prone, since you have to make sure the `Resolve` method will return the same `systemSettingService` object provided to `MyController`. IMHO it is better to use a DI container exclusively where it clearly makes things simpler.

In case `Validate` is a method of a helper class `Validator`, the same measures apply: passing the `ISystemSettingService` object directly to the method is not inherently wrong, but passing it to the constructor of `Validator` and making `Validate` non-static will probably result in more maintainable code.

Comment: My babbling meant to say `Validate` is a static function in a static class. Suppose I made the Helper class non-static, without DI then I would still have to have an instance of the `_systemSettingService` where ever I used the helper class - something that I may not necessarily have without passing the instance all over the place - would this scenario make you use DI? If yes, how would I create the helper class as and when needed in the code?

Comment: @Rick: a non-static helper class which was formerly static can most probably constructed in the constructor of `MyController` and assigned to a new member variable `_validator`. So instead of writing `Validator.Validate(userData, _systemSettingService)` you will have to write `_validator.Validate(userData)`.

Answer (score 0):

> Now I also have some static helper classes/functions

This is where you are going wrong.

Normally as in @docbrowns answer I would recommend having a non static class with a construction parameter, much the same as your controller.

However! I  notice the name of you class implies (to me at least) that the values provided by `ISystemSettingService` are unchanging setup parameters for you application?

In this case I would go further and try to eliminate the service altogether. Loading this type of settings from the app.config file and injecting them directly as the appropriate value type into services that require them.

My feeling on this issue is that although providing config settings dynamically from a service or database does give you a 'control panel' for your deployed application. You are much better in the long run having these settings managed by deployment. This gives an audit trail and more surety around how exactly a deployed service will be running, without having to take into account network connectivity, caching or other errors

Comment: Hi, they are likely never to change but the user wants to be able to change them if desired, so they need to be in the database. I think you're correct about the non-static class. I guess anything that depends on a service, for example, should not be static.